# My $.ajax POST method work on my localhost but doesn´t when I upload it on hosting

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm very new to the whole website building and I came across this problem which I can't solve.

So... I have a code that gets data from my checkbuttons and other inputs and then send it through $.ajax method POST (I already tried also $.post method) to my database. 
When I programmed it on my localhost everything worked fine ... My inputs were sent to my database with no problem ..But when I uploaded my website to hosting server it just doesn't work ...When I check HTTP response it also sends 200 OK .. And I can see in the column parameters that the input parameters were sent ...I don't know where to search for problem, please someone help me .

This is my ajax method:

```
 $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: '/automaticke_nastavenie.php',
      data: {id: 'automat',teplota: teplota, vlh_vzduch: vlh_vzduch, cas:cas, trvanie:trvanie, opakovanie:opakovanie, vlh_poda:vlh_poda}


                })
```

This is my automaticke_nastavenie.php script

```
<?php
require 'dbh.php';
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if($_POST['id']=='automat'){

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $teplota=$_POST['teplota'];
    $vlh_vzduch=$_POST[ 'vlh_vzduch'];
    $cas=$_POST['cas'];
    $trvanie=$_POST['trvanie'];
    $opakovanie=$_POST['opakovanie'];
    $vlh_poda=$_POST['vlh_poda'];

    $sql="UPDATE nastavenia  SET  Nastavenie_id='$id',Nas_tep='.$teplota.',Nas_vlh_vzduch='.$vlh_vzduch.',Nas_cas='$cas',Nas_trvanie='.$trvanie.',Nas_opakovanie='.$opakovanie.',Nas_vlh_poda='.$vlh_poda.' WHERE ID=1";
    $conn->query($sql);
```

And this is the response I get from server :

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 13:59:04 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 0
server: awex
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-request-id: 68bc0397b80de36149c337c116934e56
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Data truncated for column 'Nas_tep' at row 1 in /storage/ssd2/053/12722053/public_html/automaticke_nastavenie.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/ssd2/053/12722053/public_html/automaticke_nastavenie.php(22): mysqli-&gt;query('UPDATE nastaven...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/storage/ssd2/053/12722053/public_html/automaticke_nastavenie.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
```

Comment: That's not the response, those are the response _headers_.  View the actual raw response.  If the raw response is empty, add some debugging output to you PHP to track down where things are going wrong.

Comment: @PatrickQ sorry but how can I access that?

Comment: Probably the same way you're viewing the headers.  In your browser's developer tools, open the network inspector, click the specific request to open the details, then click the response tab.

Comment: Oh okay, I can see now that it is empty... I will try the debugging then.

Comment: Also, because someone else is bound to mention it, you should really be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead of injecting variables directly into your query.  Not only is it safer, but it will often prevent you from making mistakes like the one that is likely the culprit here.

Comment: Enable error reporting: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see in the response as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: And to clarify Patrick's last comment more clearly: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Okay so far I don't have any luck with debugging (lack of knowledge-it will take some time to actually learn how to debugg something :D ) but I tried enable that error reporting and it actually work I think ..it gave me response ,I will update it up in my question

Comment: @user7828716  That error means that the size of the data that you're trying to put in that column is larger than the size allowed by the column definition.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me btw ,I really appreciate it... I don't understand how is that possible though ...I don' have any restrictions on the column sizes and most of them are just numbers or 1/0 ...

Comment: Can't it be that I'm calling the query wrong?  Is  $conn->query($sql) the appropriate way to call it?

Comment: @user7828716  As we've indicated, the _preferred_ way would actually be to use prepared statements.

Comment: @PatrickQ okay thank you, I'm going to rewrite it :) hopefully it will be the issue...I just don't get why it worked on my localhost ...

Comment: Okay after correcting minor mistakes the main problem really was those prepared statements, it is working now :) THANK YOU @PatrickQ